# Method "Range of Object _Worksheet, Error:1004"

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim CatSh As Worksheet
Dim Cat(1 To 9) As Range
Set CatSh = Worksheets("Categories")
  For i = LBound(Cat) To UBound(Cat) 
  Set Cat(i) = CatSh.Range(CatSh.Range(CatSh.Cells(2, i)),CatSh.Range(CatSh.Cells(2, i)).End(xlDown))
  Next i
```

This simple code crashes at the 5th line. I tried several combinations of CatSh.Range and none worked. Same error every time. I am desperate for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that line to:

```
Set Cat(i) = CatSh.Range(CatSh.Cells(2, i),CatSh.Cells(2, i).End(xlDown))
```

Range of one Cells does not work, and is redundant.

Comment: @ViktorZafirovski Glad it worked.  Please mark as correct, by clicking the green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.  It will close the question as being answered.

Comment: God, thank you. I was looking for that option and gave up. I wanted to give you best answer. There we go. :)